# Xcode, ios and the Iphone 5 - resizing images

Tags: iphone, image-resizing

(Xcode 4.6.3, ios app being developed for base SDK 4.3)

I'm working on an app that loads in images in the following sequence:

- Splash screen loads as normal, then a full screen ad is displayed, then the splash screen image is loaded again,then an animation of 4-5 images is loaded,  then the app displays the first tableview.

Thing is, I've added the -568h image as well as the @2x image and that takes care of the splash screen but then the code loads the splash image again programmatically (as well as the other images for the animation).

The @2x image is automatically substituted when viewing on a retina iPhone 4 but there's no auto substitution for the iPhone 5 -568h image.

From reading I've found [this possible substitution](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/20-iPhone5-568h-image-loading) using method swizzling but I think there must be a better way to do this. Is there no auto-detect feature that detects the presence of the 568h image the same way the @2x images are loaded?

What are my options for loading the higher res version of the images and what can I do about the ad I'm loading from an JSON feed (it's an image as well)?

Thanks!

Here's a screen grab of my xcode file explorer showing the relevant file, default.png in its various formats.

[image: The files]

Comment: it does auto detect. are you sure your -568h images are named correctly?

Comment: Hi, yes it appears to autodetect on the initial load. However, when the image is then loaded in again programmatically it doesn't. So initially there's no problem with @2x and -568h images, then I try to load Default.png and it doesn't show the -568h version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no auto load method for giraffe mode (4") iOS device.

You option are to use either the swizzling method you found or write you own method fro laoding images.

What I've come up with in regards to loading image of a server, is to have the server supply me with an image in a size that I request. Meaning, I take the size of the view and pass that as x,z parameter to the server. Which will then resize the image correctly (or load different one) and returns that.

Also be aware that in the iOS HIG it is said you should not prolong the loading of your app. I've had apps reject where there was an ad presented.

Comment: Wow, ok that seems like a pretty big oversight by Apple but presumably the Swizzling method I linked to should work. Hopefully.